# how can I reduce the space between horizontal line when using the tooltip css

Tags: html, css

I need to add top and bottom horizontal lines for the heading. I am also using tooltip css, but this increases the space at the top and bottom of the heading. How can I reduce the space. Thanks!

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
        

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

hr{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
  }
```

```html
<hr>
<div class="tooltip"><h1 >MAIN HEADING</h1>
<span class="tooltiptext">Help text goes here</span>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change CSS property: `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` (note: Tooltip will appear below the line) - you can see the actual demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/a7w2ve1f/

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Bell. I added an extra option in the css to put the text on left of the heading top: -1px; left: 100%;. It took care of the text appearing after the <hr>

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,